# slack api files.upload error: not_in_channel

Tags: slack-api

trying to upload a file from a build server following the doc: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

And also using bot token: https://api.slack.com/authentication/basics

I am getting the error: {"ok":false,"error":"not_in_channel"}

Appreciate any help and pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when a bot oauth token is used and the bot isn't in the target channel(s).

To fix:

- Go into target channel(s)
- Type `/invite @BOT_NAME`
- Retry the request